# Center the middle part of a three part equation in align environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, positioning, align

I have an inequality in a *align* environment:

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames}]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath}



\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

D'où, au seuil de $95\%$,
\begin{align*}
-1.95996        &\leq  \sqrt{n} (\frac{\overline{X}-\mu}{\sigma})  && \leq 1.95996 \\
\mu -\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}*1.95996   &\leq   \overline{x}  && \leq \mu +\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}*1.95996
\end{align*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

But I am not pleased with the result.
[image]

The *&&* "trick" I found here makes it better, but I would like the center part to be centered. How can I do that ?

Additionnaly, why is there so much space at the right of my center part ?

Comment: I don't think it should be centered, but might look better if you replace `\begin{align*}` by `\begin{alignat*}{2}` (note the arg) and `\end{align*}` by `\end{alignat*}`

Comment: That solves the spacing issue, thanks. Why so you think it should not be centered ?

Comment: Un even spacing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can type this to solve your problem:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
D'où, au seuil de $95\%$,

\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{rcccl}
    -1.95996 &\leq & 
    \sqrt{n} (\frac{\overline{X}-\mu}{\sigma})  
    & \leq & 1.95996 \\
    \mu -\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}*1.95996 &\leq &
    \overline{x} & 
    \leq &\mu +\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}*1.95996
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{rcccl}
    -1.95996 &\leqslant & 
    \sqrt{n} \left(\cfrac{\overline{X}-\mu}{\sigma}\right) & 
    \leqslant & 1.95996 \\
    \mu -\cfrac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} \times 1.95996 &\leqslant & 
    \overline{x} &
    \leqslant &\mu +\cfrac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} \times 1.95996
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Also, for French typography, you should use `\leqslant` and `\geqslant` symbols instead of `\geq` and `\leq`.

Comment: Thanks, it solves the aligment issue, but it reduces the size of the display of my equation. Why is it so and can it be solved ?

Comment: I edit the answer with the `\cfrac{}{}` instead of `\frac{}{}` to have the space required. I also add `\times` instead of `*`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution: I define a `\eqmathbox` command, base on the `eqparbox` package, which uses a tag as an optional argument. All `\eqmathbox`es with the same tag will have the length of the widest among them.At least two compilations are necessary

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames}]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath}
\usepackage{eqparbox}

\let\leq\leqslant
\let\geq\geqslant
\newcommand\eqmathbox[2][]{\eqmakebox[#1]{\ensuremath{\displaystyle#2}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

D'où, au seuil de $95\%$,
\begin{alignat*}{2}
-1.95996 &\leq \eqmathbox[R]{\sqrt{n} \Bigl(\frac{\overline{X}-\mu}{\sigma}\Bigr)} && \leq 1.95996 \\
\mu -\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}*1.95996 &\leq \eqmathbox[R]{\overline{X}} && \leq \mu +\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}*1.95996
\end{alignat*}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]